# Count and group by not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select count(*),manager_id
from departments
group by manager_id;
```

this is my idea of how to, but it dosent gives me the amount of employees for each manager

Comment: show your related table schema  (departemets and employees)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are selecting from the wrong table, the logic seems correct but the fact that you are selecting from a table call `departments` is a little suspicious.

Do you have an employee tables? Does it contains a `manager_id` column? If so:

```
select count(*),manager_id
from employees
group by manager_id;
```

If employee tables has only `department_id` column then :

```
SELECT d.manager_id,count(*)
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN departments d
 ON(e.department_id = d.id)
```

Comment: After upvote, I add if exists a table of manager, you can query that table with a subquery with a number of linked employees, so if a manager has not employee under his, you'll get zero as information.

Comment: I agree that there are some cases it should be done, and you can also query the `manager_id` from `departments` and left join to `employees` , but I highly doubt that it's possible for a manager not having at least 1 employee under him.. @JoeTaras

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample table from the HR schema

```
select  MANAGER_ID, count(*), count(distinct EMPLOYEE_ID) 
from HR.EMPLOYEES
group by MANAGER_ID
order by 1 nulls first;
```

gives

```
MANAGER_ID   COUNT(*) COUNT(DISTINCTEMPLOYEE_ID)
---------- ---------- --------------------------
                    1                          1 
       100         14                         14 
       101          5                          5 
       102          1                          1
```

Note the first row, with manager IS NULL - i.e. there is a one employee without a manager.

Not also that I use both `count(*)`and  `count(distinct EMPLOYEE_ID)`. This is not relevant for this table, where `EMPLOYEE_ID` is PK, but in general case the former returns the *number of record* the latter the *number of employees* (which can be lower).

Answer (score -1):

I have faced a similar problem of yours.
**Try adding inside the count the id that you are counting ie employeeid**.
If it still doesnt work after that try adding the same id in the group by.